# Understanding numpy's lstsq

Tags: python, numpy, least-squares

I understand the idea of the sum of least square solutions. The parameters of the solution reflect the coefficients that minimize the squared error. But I am having trouble understanding the [`lstsq`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html) function available from `numpy.linalg`. For example, I tried the following:

```
m1 = np.asarray([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8]])

m2 = np.asarray([[9,10],[11,12],[13,14],[15,16]])


solution = np.linalg.lstsq(m1, m2)[0]
```

The value of `solution` is:

```
array([[-7., -8.],
   [ 8.,  9.]])
```

What does this output mean? I cannot visualize/understand this result.

Comment: Using that same data and your understanding of of a least squares fit, what did you expect the result to be?

Comment: @wwii I have known least square error to be a single value when working with regression problems. I could understand function. It accepting a matrix and giving out a matrix.

Answer (score 3):

I'll go out on a limb. The method returns `m` and `c` for the equation `y=mx+c`. When you pass a 2d array for the `b` parameter, you get two fits - one for the first column and one for the second; as if you were asking for fits on two different data sets/vectors.

```
In [22]: sol
Out[22]: 
array([[-7., -8.],
       [ 8.,  9.]])

In [23]: sol[:,0], sol[:,1]
Out[23]: (array([-7.,  8.]), array([-8.,  9.]))

In [24]: np.linalg.lstsq(m1,m2[:,0])[0]
Out[24]: array([-7.,  8.])

In [25]: np.linalg.lstsq(m1,m2[:,1])[0]
Out[25]: array([-8.,  9.])


In [30]: np.linalg.lstsq(m1, np.array([9,11,13,15]))[0]
Out[30]: array([-7.,  8.])

In [31]: np.linalg.lstsq(m1, np.array([10,12,14,16]))[0]
Out[31]: array([-8.,  9.])
```

Answer (score 2):

Your question is more or less a math one. `np.linalg.lstsq(m1, m2)` finds `x`  such that `m1(x) = m2`, similar to solving `Ax = b`.

Since `m1` and `m2`are both 4 by 2, for the left hand side multiplication to be compatible, `x`should be 2 by 2.